# INSERT query from trigger inserts NULL

Tags: t-sql, triggers, null, sql-insert

I have the following query in SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @issueid numeric(10,0)
DECLARE @domain nvarchar (255)

SET @issueid = (SELECT issueid FROM issues WHERE issueid = 4850)
SET @domain = (SELECT fielddata FROM customfielddata WHERE issueid = @issueid AND customfieldid = 99)

PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @issueid) + ': ' + @domain
```

It outputs the result as expected:

```
4850: www.domain.com
```

When I have the same query in a trigger, it inserts the `@issueid` value correctly in the first column, but `NULL` in place of `@section_name` in the 2nd column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_website_sections
   ON  gemini_issues
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT issuetypeid FROM inserted) = 58 BEGIN

        DECLARE @issueid numeric(10,0)
        DECLARE @domain nvarchar (255)

        SET @issueid = (SELECT issueid FROM inserted)
        SET @domain = (SELECT fielddata FROM customfielddata WHERE issueid = @issueid AND customfieldid = 99)

        INSERT INTO website_sections VALUES (@issueid, @domain);
    END

END
```

Can someone help figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more work I realised that because the row in `customfielddata` is created only after a row is created in `issues` (the 2nd is the primary table, and the 1st stores supplementary data for created records), the query on `customfielddata` will return `NULL`.

And trying to concatenate a string with a `NULL` returns a `NULL` and that's what's inserted into the row.

Mystery solved.